# Calculating the number of bars in a bar chart in dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I want to adjust width of bar charts based on number of bars appearing on my bar chart. Here is my chart which is displaying enough records which are fit to the width and is displayed nicely. [image]

Here is another scenario in which only two bars are displayed in same width, Which looks odd. [image]

For this situation I need to adjust the width of charts according to the number of bars, so that my chart will look pretty.

Here is the part of my script

```
var width = ??;   // Here how should I calculate width based on the number of bars? 
redrawCustomerCodeBarChart
        .width(width)
        .height(400)
        .margins({top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 70, left: 30})
        .dimension(customerNamer)
        .group(customerNameGroupr)
        .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(newCoh.map(function (d) {return d.customerName; })))
        .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .elasticY(true)
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .on('renderlet',function(chart){
              chart.selectAll("g.x text")
                .attr('dx', '-15')
                .attr('transform', "rotate(-55)");
            })
         .on('filtered.monitor', function(d) {
               // return d.key + ' (' + d.value + ')';
               if(d.value !== undefined)
                size= d.value;
            })
        .controlsUseVisibility(true);
```

Comment: Can we use `.valueAccessor` or `.keyAccessor` in this case which returns key value pair

Comment: Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most dc.js charts, the data is read from `group.all()`. So the number of bars is simply

```
customerNameGroupr.all().length
```

and then multiply appropriately.

If the number of bars may change as stuff is filtered (using [`remove_empty_bins`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#remove-empty-bins) for example), then you'd want to set the width prior to each redraw:

```
chart.on('preRedraw', function(chart) {
    chart.width(chart.group().all().length * BAR_WIDTH);
});
```

That might be messy though.

Comment: and can you say which attribute will be used to set or fix the Width of bars.

Comment: Or can't we set the width of bar charts as auto. And Thanks Gordon :)

Comment: Interesting, it looks like the bar width is always calculated and there's no way to set it directly. So I think your technique of setting the chart width is the best you can do.

Comment: they should actually give an option for that :) anyway thanks, from 2 days I  have been thinking of how to do it then the best I can do is to post it here.

Comment: If we want to calculate the total number of filtered records after `FilterAll`, how can it be done?. When we say `ndx.size()` which will always return size of  whole dataset. If this is solved, will do a great help while updating `size` of table records (total records after filtering rather than whole dataset size). I have been working on it and found a solution which is quite a logic and It makes my code complex. Any suggestions

Comment: Apparently the easiest way to do this is to use `counter = crossfilter.groupAll()` to create an object which reduces all filtered rows. The default reduction counts rows. Then call `counter.value()` wherever you need the number of records.

Comment: I tried it but `crossfilter.groupAll is not a function` its an error.

Comment: I meant the crossfilter object you got from calling the crossfilter function. The one you create dimensions from.

Comment: [Here's the doc](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#crossfilter_groupAll)